# Devilish curly quotes

Tags: php, encoding

I have a InDesign script that converts a page into JSON format.

However this comes with smart "curly" double  quotes instead of the normal ones (" "). Of course this produces an invalid JSON file.

Trying to solve the problem, as I needed to do some other operations with PHP on these files, I've tryied to embrace this problem and solve it on the file upload.

Turns out, that the function only works (not allways) on quotes produced by InDesign in a Windows PC. If you run the script on MAC, and upload the file, it won't work at all because the encoding seems to be different. I've tried other solutions that this one, but, they wouldn't produce any result at all.

Here's the script.

```
    function quoteReplacer($file)
    {



        $string = file_get_contents($file);

        $string = to_utf8($string);
        $bits = array('\xe2\x80\x9c', '\xe2\x80\x9d', '\xe2\x80\x98', '\xe2\x80\x99','â','â');
        $string = str_replace($bits,'"',$string);

        file_put_contents($file,$string); 




        //file_put_contents($file,$string);

    }

    function to_utf8( $string ) { 
            return iconv( 'CP1250', 'UTF-8', $string); 
    }
```

Comment: You mean with the InDesign script? I really tried everything to export with the straight quotes but it just doesn't work... 

With this PHP script, if the JSON file is generated on a MAC, the encoding seems to be different, and the script does not work and it gives an error (haven't got the MAC file here. will edit ASAP with the error given on this case).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This script should work:

```
// First, replace UTF-8 characters.
$text = str_replace(
 array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6"),
 array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
 $text);
// Next, replace their Windows-1252 equivalents.
 $text = str_replace(
 array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133)),
 array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
 $text);
```

To replace all the strange characters that could clog up your JSON.
courtesy: [link](http://www.toao.net/48-replacing-smart-quotes-and-em-dashes-in-mysql).

Alternatively you could have them turn it off on all workstations by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> +  <kbd>the quote key next to Enter</kbd> for MAC, the equivalent on pc is probably <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> or you can find it in [preferences](http://www.thegraphicmac.com/how-turn-curly-quotes-adobe-indesign).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems to Work on windows, so +1. I'll wait for being able to test with a Mac, and then if it works, I'll accept it ;)