# parsed Result from a webpage contains invalid format texts?

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing

Here I am trying to parse a webpage and get the contents.. http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/companyOfficers?symbol=AOS

Here is my [code](http://codepad.org/yovOddYi) that does the parsing along with the sample result attached.

Now if you see in the sample result array, in the description field few details are in invalid format.. for eg. the original 'description' contains (“Bemis”) in the webpage but it is displayed as (├ó┬Ç┬£Bemis├ó┬Ç┬¥) in the parsed result(see description field in sample result). check the url's page source and try searching 'Bemis'. what possibily could be the reason.. how to resolve it.? I also tried

```
$html_source = str_replace('“','"',$html_source); 
$html_source = str_replace('”','"',$html_source);
```

but couldn't able to get it right.. help me modify the code such that it ll give the correct parsed result.

Comment: For your `str_replace` lines, check to make sure your code editor is also set for UTF-8 encoding. This could be one problem. You might also want to explicitly set UTF-8 encoding when you initialize `DOMDocument`.

Comment: sorry didnt get you.. can you explain me clearly..or if possible can you give the edited correct code @cpilko

Comment: I use Notepad++ for quick and dirty coding. The default encoding of a Notepad++ document is ANSI. So if I copied and pasted your code into my Notepad++, the `“` in my ANSI-encoded php code may not equal the `“` in the UTF-8 encoded document being compared. If I change the encoding of my code, it could fix it. That and change line 8 of your code to `$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');`. It should default to UTF-8, but you can never be too sure.

Comment: Really, this is just a shot in the dark...

Comment: still cant able to fix it..giving same result.. try the editing code with your code editor and compile it.. check if it gives the correct result. @cpilko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this after line 5 of your code worked for me:

```
// First, replace UTF-8 characters.
$html_source = str_replace(
 array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6"),
 array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
 $html_source);

// Next, replace their Windows-1252 equivalents.
$html_source = str_replace(
 array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133)),
 array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
 $html_source);
```

Thanks to @Wolfe in this SO thread: [Devilish curly quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007613/devilish-curly-quotes)